# Let's fun in the kitchen

Tags: grammar

"Let's fun in the kitchen"  or "Let's have fun in the kitchen" 
which is correct grammar?
Giuseppe

Comment: “Have fun” is the correct expression.

Comment: thank you for the answer. But since translator give the some translation. Could you explain me the difference?

Comment: @GiuseppeScorziello Make sure to upvote the accepted answer too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Have fun" is more correct rather than "let's fun" because "fun" is a noun, not a verb. "Have," however, acts as a verb in "have fun."

Check out this web-page for reference: https://english-the-easy-way.com/English_ESL/English_Verb_Usage_Have.htm

Comment: Fun is actually also a verb, meaning to tease, mainly in AmE.